# Autodesk Forge: Measurement and Slice not working - Not an instance of THREE.Object3D

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have created a Forge Viewer using version 7 of the viewer3d.js and can view a model within it.

My issue is that the measurement and slice tools aren't working as expected. 
FYI I'm using typescript - angular 8.

I'm expecting the graphics to look like this for a slice:

[image]

Instead the plane and gyroscope symbol never appear:
[image]

Similarly with the measurement tool, the mouse cursor changes to the measurement cursor, but when i click on a surface, nothing happens.

Here is my code for loading the viewer:

```
  loadViewer(forgeTokenData, modelUrn) {


    options = {
      env: 'AutodeskProduction',
      api: 'derivativeV2',
      getAccessToken: (onSuccess) => {
        onSuccess((forgeTokenData as any).access_token, (forgeTokenData as any).expires_in);
    }};

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {

      // Find the element where the 3d viewer will live.
      const htmlElement = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');

      if (htmlElement) {
        // Create and start the viewer in that element
        const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlElement);
        viewer.start();

        const documentId = 'urn:' + this.removeBase64Padding(modelUrn);

        console.log(documentId);

        this.loadDocument(documentId, viewer);
      }});
  }
```

I've also loaded the styles and scripts in my index.html head:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>testing</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js" ></script>
</head>
```

Not sure why this is happening. Are there any other styles or scripts i'm missing?

I've noticed these errors in the console when i click on the slice / measurement tool:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried on another model? (just to be check if it related to the 3D model or if it's related to the implementation tiself).

Comment: Yeah I've tried a Revit model with just a few walls and a floor, also tried the model above in a different viewer and all works fine. Looks like a three.js issue, does forge use an older version of three?

Comment: Yes, I don't think they systematically use the latest version, as can be inferred from [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/webpack-and-threejs-forge-applications).

Comment: Thanks for the info @vicraj , I have asked a new question to see how I can exclude THREE.js so it isn't loaded twice - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295840/angular-8-webpack-three-js-loading-twice