# Angular 8: Webpack - THREE.js loading twice

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm creating a web app using Angular which integrates the Autodesk forge viewer javscript library.

The forge viewer.js library is included in the forge viewer.js itself, which is a customized version of the THREE.js release r71.

Because of this, I am seeing some unexpected results in my app:

`THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D`

From a bit of research, this is because THREE.js is being loaded twice into my app. I've tried uninstalling three.js from node_modules, but this causes build errors:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\source\repos\Testing\appname\appname-SPA\node_modules\three\build\three.min.js'`

This error is removed when i exclude THREE.js in tsconfig.json, but I'm still seeing unexpected results.

Apparently a fix in a React app is to mention THREE.js in externals when using webpack:

```
const config = {
    …
    externals: {
        three: 'THREE'
    },
```

But angular doesn't include webpack.config.js. How would I go about excluding THREE.js?

Comment: It's not my favorite method, but you can augment the webpack config as seen [here](https://netbasal.com/customize-webpack-configuration-in-your-angular-application-d09683f6bd22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant reproduce your error since im not sure how you are importing the forge-viewer script.

By default the forge-viewer script is imported via a script tag in you head tag in index.html, this links to an autodesk cdn. This should not prompt any node modules to be installed into your angular project.
You however do need to install the the forge-viewer  [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-viewer).This will give you typed definitions for the forge-viewer functions.

I would just do a clean `ng new` and add scripts and packages accordingly:

- Initialize a new angular project.
- Add the viewer script and css to your index.html inside your angular project. This will prompt the scripts to be loaded as soon as possible when running the project.
- Install the forge-viewer [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/forge-viewer), these typings include the three.js typings aswell.
- Add `"types": ["forge-viewer"]` to your `tsconfig.app.json` under `compilerOptions` to solve initial compiler errors.

Alternatively you could try and remove all forge-viewer related packages from your current project and do step 2 to 4 as described above.

Comment: Thanks Sam, steps 2-4 didn't fix my existing app, I was already importing the forge-viewer scripts as you have mentioned. I wasn't aware types were available for so that's great. but creating a new app works as expected. Since I have an extra version of three.js in my existing app, it looks like the forge viewer version of three.js is conflicting with the version in node_modules

Comment: Good stuff, did this fix your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59271906/autodesk-forge-measurement-and-slice-not-working-not-an-instance-of-three-obj) question ?

Comment: Turns out i was being an idiot and had a link to three.js in my angular.json scripts array from testing the app without forge in the past, which was causing build errors after uninstalling three using npm. Add the answer to my previous question and i'll accept. Cheers!